# Recent privileges, badge and reputation

Tags: feature-request, support, ios-app

In the iOS app, I can't find the function that shows:

> Recent achievements: privileges, badge and reputation earned

The site shows this information.

I think it's a useful function to monitor reputation changes; Am I not seeing it, or is a missing feature?

Comment: In the meantime, you can find some of that in the Feed